# Laravel | bloquear vários logins com o mesmo user

Tags: php, laravel

Preciso de uma ideia de como solucionar o problema do laravel do mesmo usuário poder logar em várias máquinas diferentes ao mesmo tempo.

Mandem exemplos ou uma ideia de por onde começar a procurar pela solução.

A ideia seria um fluxo parecido com isso:

Se o usuário logar com uma conta que já esteja logada em um PC, a que estava logada vai ser automaticamente deslogada e vai receber um aviso explicando o que aconteceu.

Comment: Como assim? Talvez eu não esteja a perceber bem a questão, mas tanto quanto sei, é possível fazer login com a mesma conta, a partir de diferentes computadores. O que é que estás a tentar fazer, ao certo?

Comment: Isso se trata de uma instalação padrao ou um sistema já customizado? Essa limitação não existe por padrão no Laravel.

Comment: o que eu quero realmente é bloquear isso.
Por exemplo, não quero que duas pessoas diferentes consigam fazer login na mesma conta em máquinas diferentes, quero que quando um usuário logar, ele verifique se a conta já está logada e se estiver ele deslogue da primeira máquina.

Comment: eu tenho um sistema que utiliza o metodo de autenticação padrão do laravel, porém, não quero que um usuário logue em máquinas diferentes com o mesmo login. caso ele faça isso, o primeiro pc que foi logado se deslogue automaticamente

Comment: Veja isso: https://blog.especializati.com.br/login-unico-no-laravel/